# How to get sold item details using different effectivedate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, time

Actually, I want to get sold item information. but i have different prices according to different dates so how can I get proper sold amount and number of qty.

For example, I have this data:

```
ItemId     Price     EffectiveDate
----------------------------------
ABC        200       2020-05-01
BCD        250       2020-05-01
ABC        250       2020-05-10
BCD        300       2020-05-10
```

Now suppose Item ABC is sold 20 Quantities everyday between 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-09 and after 2020-05-09 10 more item has been sold in three days. So i wanted to count and value

If I pass date 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-05 then

```
ItemId        Qty       Value
---------------------------------
ABC           100       20,000
```

but if I pass date 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-13

```
Itemid        Qty       Value
---------------------------------
ABC           260       56,000
```

where value is (20 * 9 * 200) + (20 * 4 * 250)

- 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-09 is 9 day with effective price 200
- 2020-05-10 to 2020-05-3 is 4 day with effective price 250

Please help

Comment: You need to fix your design here. YOu will never be able to do this accurately, especially when you get more prices. Fix the design, itemise your orders, store when they were purchased.

Comment: Do you have quantities table?